# Integrating NuGet into a large, existing code base, with a shared packages directory and a shared solutions directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget

**Q: Is it possible/feasible, to have a multiple solutions stored in a single 'Solutions' directory, and multiple NuGet packages stored in another single 'Packages' directory, and for everything to work nicely with different versions?**

Further details...

For example: I have 2 projects. ProjectA requires Newstonsoft.Json.4.5.11, ProjectB requires Newstonsoft.Json.5.0.6.

For sake of example I have a solution file for both. I need all my solution files in the same directory (this is just the process that is followed, all the solutions in a directory are built in turn).

By default NuGet will create a `packages` directory alongside each solution file.

I have created a `nuget.config` file to allow me to store packages in a single directory, called 'SharedPackages', following this answer: [Nu-Get & issue with project level dependences for projects referenced by multiple solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277925/nu-get-issue-with-project-level-dependences-for-projects-referenced-by-multipl/7908976#7908976)

```
<settings>
    <repositoryPath>..\SharedPackages</repositoryPath>
</settings>
```

This works great so far, so my structure is:

```
\Projects\ProjectA 
\Projects\ProjectB 
\Solutions 
\SharedPackages
```

If I create ProjectB, it has Json.NET 4.5.11 by default. If I go to `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` I have the option to update it to version 5.0.6. This is great as ProjectB needs the newer version. What is even better is now in my `Shared Packages` directory I have a directory for both versions of Json.NET side-by-side, so ProjectA can use the older version.

However, now I want to create ProjectC as a full MVC4 Web Application. For JQuery, you get version 1.8.2 currently when creating an ASP.NET MVC4 application in VS2012. I also get Knockout 2.2.0.

My process is, I delete the default `packages` directory, move the new solution to the `Solutions` directory alongside the existing `nuget.config` and edit the new solution file to update the relative path to the new .csproj file. Then when I build, NuGet Package Manager restores the extra packages I need (that weren't in use by ProjectA and ProjectB) to the `Shared Packages` directory. However... I get build errors, it cannot resolve some references including DotNetOpenAuth, WebGrease, System.Spatial... the references are pointing to the `packages` directory, not the `SharedPackages` directory...

As an aside: if I Enable Package Restore for solution, then it also tries to restore them to a `packages` folder within the `Solutions` directory by default, instead of restoring them to the `SharedPackages` directory.

Around about this point I realise that just creating the `nuget.config` file wasn't enough for ProjectA and ProjectB either, although they appeared to be working originally, the references in the .csproj. file are pointing to the `bin` folder beneath the project file, instead of my `SharedPackages` directory.

So I manually 'Find and Replace' `..\packages` with `..\..\SharedPackages` for all the references. I have to do this for ProjectA, ProjectB and ProjectC. Now everything builds and seems to work OK, new packages go into the right place.

Now, if I go back to ProjectA, and add the Knockout package, this is version 2.3.0. This installs happily alongside the other Knockout package in use by Project C which is version 2.2.0. Doing this also installs JQuery 2.0.3, alongside JQuery 1.8.2. So far so good.

Just as a sanity check, I create another Web Application - ProjectD, move the files around, update the references in the solution and the project. This time everything builds first time. I try and update WebGrease in ProjectD to see if it will retain the older version for ProjectC. This results in more issues, it installs it to the packages directory instead. WebGrease seems to have a separate config setting as well `<WebGreaseLibPath>`... it won't seem to restore...

I then go back to ProjectB and try 'Update All' - it looks like the files that already exist are updated in `SharedPackages`, with new version directories alongside the existing ones, but any new dependencies (e.g. now I have a reference to Owin.dll) get placed in the `packages` folder :( If I delete the `packages` folder, and the `bin` folder within ProjectB, then build the ProjectB solution, understandably I get build errors, the packages aren't automatically restored to the `SharedPackages` directory at any point.

**Is it even possible to set NuGet to update packages in a common directory other than `packages` alongside the solution?**

**Would it be easier to just use the default `packages` folder, instead of `SharedPackages`, or would I still have problems?**

This is turning into way too many questions. To try and keep it in scope, has anyone attempted a similar setup, what obstacles did they overcome and how did they manage it, or did they give up altogether? If you gave up, how did you end up using NuGet to manage packages in a massive code base?

*I appreciate this is close to this question, which was well answered for that particular question, however the use case here is slightly different: [NuGet and multiple solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431845/nuget-and-multiple-solutions). It is also pretty much identical to this question: [Setting up a common nuget packages folder for all solutions when some projects are included in multiple solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-sulutions-when-some-projects-a), but I have decided to add this anyway as that question is more focused on the having different configurations for different solutions, whereas here I want all the packages in one place, I just want to implement it and see if it is possible. Also I think the troubleshooting and research time may be useful to someone.*